# How to find element with class on any depth using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that I have somewhere inside div on any depth ( maybe one or two or three, it changes over time ) with class="nested". How to find that element on any depth using JQuery ?

I tried like

`var nest=$('#container_div').find('.nested');` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Other than missing an apostrophe your code should work fine. `find()` will look for the element no matter how deep it is.

Comment: You're missing a quote. This works fine: `$('#container_div .nested')` (`.find()` is not needed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And another syntax for fun:

```
var nest = $( '.nested', '#container_div' );
```

I give jQuery a *context* of where to look for the `.nested` class.

Comment: Why? Given a context jQuery simply implements `find()` internally anyway: Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method, so $('span', this) is equivalent to $(this).find('span'). So it seems easier to simply leave it to `find()`.

Comment: Well, it's just another way to do it. Didn't say it was more effective or something :)

Answer (score 4):

`var nest=$('#container_div').find('.nested');` Maybe you forgot quote?

Comment: Or `$('#container_div .nested')`, surely?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with the other answer but:

```
var nest=$('#container_div .nested');
```

is more concise. Separating selectors with a space is the same as `find` within a selector. If for some reason you wanted to limit to direct children only,

```
var nest=$('#container_div > .nested');
```